# Bigquery- Parse_date for string column with 'April 9,2013' 'December 13,2014' and more

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I am working with a column containing multiple dates in string format with April 9,2013, December 13,2014 and so on. I did find a answer which would be good for single row of data but hasnt worked for this one.
I also tried

> SELECT PARSE_DATE('%B %d,%Y,'ColumnName')
> but it returned Error: Failed to parse input string "SaleDate"(ColumnName)

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that your table has one or more records which does not match the date format `%B %d,%Y`.  You may flush out offending records using `REGEXP_CONTAINS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(date_col, r'^(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{4}$')
```

Comment: Actually it worked but after adding a space after , in the above syntax. Thankyou for answering.